# Is there a highly exothermic reaction that the reactants can be easily regenerated from the products?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a highly exothermic reaction that the reactants can be easily regenerated from the products? Let's say you put in contact two reactants and they react and produce large amount of heat. Then can you take the products and regenerate the reactants easily?

If we put acid and alkali together, an exothermic reaction will take place. How can we regenerate the acid and alkali?

Comment: What does "easily" mean for you? Burning hydrogen is exothermic, producing hydrogen from water is relatively easy (though not necessarily cheap)

Comment: I was thinking something like pouring a liquid on a metal surface and then taking the liquid and dissolve it, electrolysise it or heat it or somehow regenerate it.

Comment: There is no free lunch, and also no perpetual motion machine. If that is not what you want, please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: I’m voting to reopen. It might not be a good question, but it’s sufficiently clear and can be answered using the fundamental laws of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 6):

Why, many reactions are like that, but there's a catch. To regenerate the reactants from the products, you'll have to put in at least as much energy as was gained from the reaction in the first place. This is the energy conservation law; there is no going around it.

Other than that, the examples are plenty. You may go with burning of hydrogen and electrolysis of water.